# Left engineering job to pursue career in software development. Will it work?

Tags: job-search, new-job

I got a full time job straight out of college as an engineer. However, I really realized that my passion was software development. I love to code.

I ended up leaving my job to pursue a career in software development. I joined a coding bootcamp and just graduated. I am just wondering how employable I am and wondering if I should have just stuck to my job as an engineer. I have made some smartphone apps on the side to show so hopefully that will help boost my resume.

Comment: It might help to know where you are. Different regions probably have different expectations as to how long people stay at a company before moving on.

Comment: @BSMP I live in the Midwest in a town with cornfields and what not. Not a big city.

Comment: @Fattie Yes but I hate lying and hiding things from people. Do you think future employers would be mad if they ever found out in the future that I actually took a job that didn't work out?

Comment: *I live in the Midwest* So the United States? When you said they had a contract, I thought this might have been a job outside the US. Was that first job a contract job? If so, did you stay the agreed upon time?

Comment: Yes the United States. Sorry I should have been more specific. And no, it was not a contract job that ended at a certain time. I was working through a contracting company though if that means anything.

Comment: I should add it's really rare that an employer would want your full and complete work history (until you're getting a security clearance for instance). Omitting jobs especially short, non-interesting stints from your resume is preferred.

Answer (score 12):

> Would any companies really want to hire someone that left their job the way I did? Doesn't it show a lack of commitment?

To be honest, it would be hard to explain that company misrepresented their position and was not because you didn't do your homework on the role or changed your mind. But why even bring the job up to begin with? 2 weeks of job experience is just not worth bringing up, because it's unlikely you made any impact at the company in such a short amount of time.

> I have a lot of projects like smartphone apps that I have made on my own that prove I have the skills, but not much to show for as far as my dedication to a company goes. I am asking, what should I do to get back in the game and learn from my mistakes so I can make up for it?

Based on what you stated in your question, your story sounds like this: **You got a degree in Electrical Engineering. You then took a job as a test engineer, but realized you loved software engineering instead. You created apps on your own, but you realized you wanted to get some formal training. You joined a bootcamp, because it seemed more practical and hands-on than a master's degree. You're ready and committed to getting an entry-level software engineering position after you graduate your bootcamp.**

Don't overcomplicate your story by talking about the two week disaster of a job. Do talk about the positives of your projects and the value you would bring to your new role.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes. However, I don't ever believe in lying. What if they asked me if there was anything else that I was doing since I left my position? Because I mean, there was about a 3 month gap between starting my bootcamp. Should I tell them then?

Comment: I also am a big stickler on not lying. There is a difference between lying and not listing unrelated job experiences however. A very junior candidate is much more likely to list every job experience they've ever had to pad their resume. This some extent hurts their resume by introducing unnecessary information. It's important to be concise and list experiences relevant to the type of role you're apply for.

Comment: If a company asks you to explain that 3 month gap in your resume, I would recommend a diplomatic answer along the lines: "I tried looking for software engineering roles, but I had trouble finding a good fit. I decided attending a bootcamp to complement my existing development skills was the best next step." I use "good fit", because it sounds either sides of the equations (you or the employer) could have said no.

Answer (score 4):

You need not disclose about the first company which you worked 2 weeks for in your future interviews. If you choose to mention it, please do not use the reason which you stated below. From a company's point of view, I see a candidate who called it quits before even attempting, or when things don't go his way.

> I get out there and they said I would be doing cloud computing (AWS) and from what I could tell it did not seem like a job I actually wanted. Little to no code from what I understood.

However in the future, when something is not to your expectation, why not give it a go first?  You might find that you like it or have an apt for it. In any job, there will always be things that are not up to your expectation, because you are working for others.

Answer (score -1):

> So **I graduated** May of 2017

and

> I joined a coding bootcamp. I am **about to graduate**.

While not important, it is still confusing ;)

Back to the subject: I think you should not worry much about it. Things like this may happen. Considering that you are quite fresh after college, it may not even weigh much with interviewers / companies - even if they will remark this and talk to you about this. It is their job to make you as insecure as possible.

To "defend" yourself if needed, you can go simple. Tell them the truth, that you understood that software is more attractive than electrical engineering, and that you are happy to enlarge your knowledge in different fields.

Also tell them that the job at that company was not what you expected - it did not involve writing software - and that it was natural to move on.

**On the other hand**, even if it not always possible, no not leave one job before you have another one - with all details clarified (e.g. how much time you will spend writing software, which activities of software development you will do...) and with signed contract.

Comment: I'm guessing it's somewhere that uses the word "graduate" a bit more loosely. The first one is a degree, the second refers to [graduating from coding boot camp].

Comment: exactly as I said: not important :) I had in mind that explanation also, I just hoped to get a more clear answer from OP.